# How to Reduce react.js project Bundle size

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, build, package.json

> I have created a project whose build size is 26mb, then i removed useless packages, dead codes and much more useless stuffs from the project and it's code been reduced to 17mb but i want to reduce it further up to 10mb, idk which packages do i need here to compress the bundle size [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlKA9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies that you need only for development like `react-testing-library`, into `devDependencies`.
That should help.
Check for images and assets might help too